# AndroidTest ERROR:D8: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

I run `dexBuilderDebugAndroidTest` on terminal(mac os m 1)

```
ERROR:D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.android.tools.r8.graph.C.P()" because "<local1>" is null
Execution failed for task ':dexBuilderDebugAndroidTest'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detachedConfiguration9'.
   > Failed to transform jetified-play-services-measurement-20.0.0-runtime.jar to match attributes {artifactType=ext-dex-dexBuilderDebugAndroidTest, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingExternalLibArtifactTransform: /Users/suriyaalee/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a39b6fa974b838a4c16296024a8c100d/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-20.0.0-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
```

This error on my terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try below lines into gradle file:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

After that do the clean project and rebuild it.

In Android Studio go to **Build --> Clean Project and after, Build --> Rebuild Project**

Comment: it doesn't work